# malloc attribute takes no arguments

Tags: c, gcc, clang, static-analysis

I've created a pair of functions:

```c
void destroy_foo(void *ptr);
void *create_foo(void);
```

As the names suggest, these function akin to `malloc` and `free`.  I'd like to use the `malloc` [gcc function attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html) to inform the compiler of this relationship so that this code would raise a warning with `-fanalyzer`:

```c
void *ptr = create_foo();
destroy_foo(ptr);
destroy_foo(ptr);
```

Following the examples from the fore-mentioned link, I did

```c
void *create_foo(void) __attribute__ ((malloc (destroy_foo)));
```

While gcc (11.4.0) is fine with this, clang (14.0.0) complains

```
error: 'malloc' attribute takes no arguments
void *create_foo(void) __attribute__ ((malloc (destroy_foo)));
                                       ^
```

My understanding was that gcc attributes worked just fine with clang.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The forms currently implemented by GCC are:

```
malloc
malloc (deallocator)
malloc (deallocator, ptr-index)
```

They are documented in [Common Function Attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html).

Clang seems to be behind in this game and implements only the first form:

[Attributes in Clang](https://releases.llvm.org/13.0.0/tools/clang/docs/AttributeReference.html#malloc)

Comment: You must remember that these ``__attribute__``s are all very implementation-defined language extensions, so it is not unexpected that different compilers exhibit differing behaviours and levels of support!